# iOS : Customizing TableViewCell - Initializing Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my TableView, I have a dataSource of NSMutableArray *currList - it contains objects of object Agent. I created customized TableCell and set up everything properly. I am finding problem while displaying data :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ChatListCell";

     // Custom TableViewCell
     ChartListCell *cell = (ChartListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
           // I believe here I am going wrong
           cell = [[ChartListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
           NSLog(@"Cell = %@", cell);  // Shows null
     }
     /*
     With UITableViewCell, things are working perfectly fine
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     }
     */
     Agent *agent = (Agent *)[currChatList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSLog(@"Agent name - %@", agent.name);   // Prints proper data
     cell.nameLabel.text = agent.name;
     cell.thumbImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:agent.photo];
     cell.timeLabel.text = agent.chatTime;

     return cell;
}
```

As you can see in above code comments, If I comment the custom ChartListCell and use UITableViewCell, it works properly. But with ChartListCell, nothing comes up and in logs I get "Cell = null" & Agent name is showing properly. 
Cell shouldn't be null. Why is it null, can anyone please help me out with this. Where am I doing mistake ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you registered your custom cell nib or class with the tableview elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Does the cell display the Agent' name/photo when you use `ChartListCell`?

Comment: Where did you create this custom cell? Storyboard? Xib?

Comment: I have created the custom cell in Xib file. In app I am using storyboard. I have not used the custom cell anywhere else in the app. No, the cell is not displaying any thing - agent name/photo/time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

import your custom cell file and try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ChartListCell";

ChartListCell *cell = (ChartListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChartListCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

}         

 Agent *agent = (Agent *)[currChatList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSLog(@"Agent name - %@", agent.name);   // Prints proper data
 cell.nameLabel.text = agent.name;
 cell.thumbImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:agent.photo];
 cell.timeLabel.text = agent.chatTime;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that NSArray *nib was the line where I was making mistake, but didn't knew what was the mistake and why NSArray * is required. From your code and question - "whether it is created in Xib or story board" I can make that this line is to init the cell from the xib file. But didn't get, Why NSArray & 0th element of NSArray is the object for the cell ??? Will wait for some time to know this point, will mark your answer as Answer soon.

Comment: using 0th element because there will be only one element in array nib. because there is only one nib file with named ChartListCell

Comment: Ok, now I understood the concept of these lines. We get the xib files from the bundle of specific name And then pick the particular file from the array. Array will have all files of specified name & as we have only 1 file of such name we pick the 0th element from the array.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Basically There are four possible approaches for making custom UITableViewCells:
If you are interested to learn all these four, it is worth to go through this link:
 http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_custom_cells which describes all these approaches beautifully.

Just go through it for sake of your knowledge.