# TableView UILabel alignment changes when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `TableView` with 3 `UILabel`: title, author name and category and a `UIImage`. All cells should look similar to this layout:

[image: Cell Layout]

Correct cell layout:

[image: Proper Label Alignment]

When the app starts for some reason some cells have the title `UILabel` alignment not as it should be:

[image: Incorrect title label alignment]

[image: Incorrect title label alignment]

After scrolling the `TableView` a few times, these cells end up with the proper alignment. I'm not quite sure what is causing this.

I have created a Custom TableView Cell class (followed this [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html))

**CustomTableViewCell.h**

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *authorLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel;
@end
```

**CustomTableViewCell.m**

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.titleLabel.frame);
    [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
}

@end
```

This is how this class is implemented in the `ViewController`:

```
@interface CurrentIssueViewController () {
    CurrentIssueModel *_currentIssueModel;
    Article *_selectedArticle;
}

@end

@implementation CurrentIssueViewController

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;
//@synthesize _feedItems;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didChangePreferredContentSize:)name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    // Create array object and assign it to _feedItems variable
    self._feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    // Create new HomeModel object and assign it to _homeModel variable
    _currentIssueModel = [[CurrentIssueModel alloc] init];

    // Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
    _currentIssueModel.delegate = self;

    // Call the download items method of the home model object
    [_currentIssueModel downloadItems];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)didChangePreferredContentSize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{
    // This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

    // Set the downloaded items to the array
    self._feedItems = items;

    [activityView stopAnimating];

    // Reload the table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of feed items (initially 0)
    return self._feedItems.count;
}

/* ================================================== */

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomTableViewCell class]])
    {
        CustomTableViewCell *textCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)cell;

        Article *article_item = self._feedItems[indexPath.row];

        NSString *fulltitle = article_item.Title;

        if (article_item.Subtitle != nil && article_item.Subtitle.length != 0) {
            fulltitle = [fulltitle stringByAppendingString:@": "];
            fulltitle = [fulltitle stringByAppendingString:article_item.Subtitle];
        }
        textCell.titleLabel.text = fulltitle;

        if ([article_item.Author isEqualToString:@"accountant"]) {
            textCell.authorLabel.text = @"";
        }
        else {
            textCell.authorLabel.text = article_item.Author;
        }

        textCell.categoryLabel.text = article_item.Cat_Name;

        textCell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        textCell.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0f];

        textCell.authorLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0f];
        textCell.categoryLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0f];
        textCell.categoryLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        NSURL *url;

        if ([article_item.ImageUrl length] != 0) {
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:article_item.ImageUrl];
        }
        else {
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"imageurl"];
        }

        [textCell.image sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_image.jpg"]];
    }
}

- (CustomTableViewCell *)prototypeCell
{
    if (!_prototypeCell)
    {
        _prototypeCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    return _prototypeCell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self configureCell:self.prototypeCell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.prototypeCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.prototypeCell.bounds));

    [self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height+1;
}

/* ================================================== */

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set selected article to var
    _selectedArticle = self._feedItems[indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];

}

#pragma mark Segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    ArticleViewController *articleVC = segue.destinationViewController;

    // Set the property to the selected article so when the view for
    // detail view controller loads, it can access that property to get the feeditem obj
    articleVC.selectedArticle = _selectedArticle;
}

@end
```

I guess it's something to do with `forRowAtIndexPath` but I can't really figure out what's the issue.

**Update:**

I noticed that there is another problem with the title `UILabel`. Whenever you select a cell, view the article in another `ViewController` and go back to the `UITableView` the title labels are positioned in the `Center Left` rather than `Top Left`. Once you scroll again the title labels adjust to the proper position.

Comment: check my answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104792/ios-customizing-tableviewcell-initializing-custom-cell/22111294#22111294 and use ` - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method and init  custom cell as per that answer and do the following may be it will helps you

Comment: thanks for your comment...I am already using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I've updated my question with that function. I'll try out what you suggested.

Comment: then try to put all code of forRowAtIndexPath to  cellForRowAtIndexPath method as par my that answer.

Comment: Same thing happens to some cells

Comment: You should add some constraints to your labels. That's exactly what constraints are used for

Comment: Yep thanks for that, had to look into more detail on constraints to see why this were not looking as they should. This post helped a lot: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have auto layout selected for the NIB/Storyboard but have not added any constraints to your cells. Add layout constraints to your cells. There is a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) that explains it in some details:

Comment: Thanks for this, constraints were not properly set. This helped me realise what was wrong: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout, your link as well. Thanks again.